# why I Can't upload videos with php?

Tags: php

I wrote that code, picked up by this forum, and i will make a easily form to upload files to my server.

```html
<?php

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma", "mov", "MP4", "MOV", "JPG", "JPEG", "GIF", "WMA", "MP3");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

/*if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mov")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {*/
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploadFiles/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "uploadFiles/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
 /* }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }*/
?>
```

but it didn't work with video files, i've tried with 38MB MP4 file...
i don't have any control on files, so why it didn't work?

P.S. I don't need any control because is a personal way to share files, mostly videos and photos, that i need, it will be active for a little time, so  i know that is risky but only few person wi know the website and however this is used only for this.

Comment: Will your server settings allow uploads that big?

Comment: ehm i don't know, where i can find those settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check/change (increase) your upload (input) server settings. These:

1) [max_input_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time)

2) [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)

3) [post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

And maybe `max_execution_time` ( I don't know your value).
Change their or via `php.ini`, or via `.htaccess` ( like setting `php_value`).

Plus change value (`20000`) at that line:

```
 ...
 && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
 ....
```

Of course, it rejects 38Mb- file.